# Changing row color based on a cell in a different row

Tags: excel, formatting, conditional-statements, vba

I have an Excel doc of projects with a status column, and each project consists of two rows. I have already used conditional formatting to change the background color of a row depending on the status, but I need to also change the color of the row below based on the same status cell. The cell in the blank row also has a blank status.

Is there a conditional formatting or macro I can use to do this? Thanks.

Comment: Use the format painter ( on home tab ) to copy and paste the conditional formatting on the entire row(s).

Comment: @pnuts you're right.  Let's say cell C5 holds the data which determines formatting...He just needs to make the conditioning in row 5 as $C5 and the conditioning in row 6 as $C5.  Then he can do the format painter for the remainder of the rows.  I assumed that since he knew conditional formatting, he knew about the $...The format painter will copy and paste the conditional formatting.

Comment: @pnuts I don't believe the question was asked well and if I could downvote, I would on this one.  Many of us are interpreting this differently.  I'm reading it that OP has data in cell(1,1) with rows 1 and 2, based on this data, then cell(3,3) has additional data which rows 3 and 4 depend, etc.  Once you get the formatting set on rows 1 and 2, then you can highlight both rows, click format painter, then shift+end+down, beginning on row 3, and you're done...

Answer (score 1):

so just reference the cell.

For example, say you have the current row want to look at the next row, column G.

In your conditional formulas:

in row "5" (for example):

```
=$g6=value
```

[edit] misred the question got things backwards, the above will change format for a cell based on the row *below*. If you want to change the format for a cell based on the row *above*, of course, just flip the logic, in short, you can reference any cell/row to change the format for a given cell within the conditional formatting[edit]

and set the background.
The $ in front of the G makes sure that no matter what column you're looking at, it'll always look at column g value. leave the 6 "floating", and it'll stay "relative" to your current row. So you're on row 5, with the formula pointing to 6, so copy that down 10 rows, and row 7 will look to row 8, etc.

Comment: Alright, I had tried that before but I didn't know that I could change the "Applies to" selection after creating the rule. Creating it with the row I want (below the cell) and then editing the rule to apply to the entire selection of rows I want to repeat it seems to work. Thank you!

Comment: yeah, "changing" conditional formatting can be touchy. I usually find it best to highlight all cells you want affected, note which cell is "active" (it'll show as the one that doesn't quite look highlighted :) ) and then put in the formula based on that cell as a reference point.

Comment: @pnuts - not quite. the formula is on row 5, so it can only change the format of row 5. it can, however, REFERENCE other rows, such as row 6 (ie $g6).

Comment: @pnuts Oh I see, yeah, the way the OP worded the question, I misread it. So yeah, should set the conditional formatting on "row 6" to =$g5=value.  Either way, the method is clear - conditional formatting can look to other cells/rows to figure out if it should format or not.

Comment: depends on how complex they are, but yeah, sure. You could either setup a really complex formula that looked at current row, and row above to see what to change to. Or you set up 2 rules, 1 to look at current row, 1 to look at previous row.

Answer (score 0):

Sat your status column is C and for that you have chosen that ColumnsA:N are highlighted yellow with a CF formula rule of:

```
=$C1="s"
```

and Applies to

```
=$A:$N
```

To extend that to colour highlight also the row immediately below each "s" in ColumnC, select C2 and adjust the rule to:

```
 =OR($C1="s",$C2="s")
```

and the Applies to range to:

```
  =$A$2:$N$1048573
```